# Issue while clicking on 'find hotels' using Selenium-Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium (web driver) - Java. I picked a travel site to do demo of automation.
On this travel site, at home webpage, I need to place following input before submit the form.

1. Provide City name
2. Date from and Date To
3. Click on Find hotel button.

I am able to do following:

1. Done
2. Done
3. **Unable to click on Find hotel button.**

On 3rd step, whenever I am clicking on 'Find button' through selenium code, it redirect page to some other website (not sure from where its redirection is coming).

My question is: is I am doing something wrong? Below are the details:

Web page source code:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
  <div class='multiSearchBox' >
    <div class='clear'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block_bottom">
    <div class="bottom">
      <button class="search" type="submit">Find Hotels</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="passengers" autocomplete="off" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</form>'
```

---

here is the button code which shows up in inspect element:

```html
<button class="search" type="submit">Find Hotels</button>
```

---

Here is my code:

```java
public void SubmitForm() {
WebElement Submit = Driver.findElement(By.className("search"));
System.out.println(Submit.getText());
Submit.submit();
}
```

I tried with following as well:

```java
Submit.click();
```

But no luck.

However, I am getting button label: 'Find Hotels' in output but page gets re-directed to some other search page.

Doing manual click 'Find hotels' button on web page works fine.

I tried with Chrome and Firefox, I am facing same problem.

Please see if some can help.

Comment: There is a chance that there is one more button with className = search on the same page. So you can write a more specific xpath for that submit button

Comment: Agree with HemChe that your locator might not be unique. You need to look into what kind of locators (xpath or css) are suitable for your situation (it depends on the full html of the webpage). I recommend using [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/firepath) as a quick, easy, and reliable way of verifying your locators before using them in webdriver.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following xpath

```
//button[text() = 'Find Hotels']
```